# Castle-Windsor: Overwrite a component in the future

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I have the following use case:

I want to register all components shared between all configurations of an application.  Then I would like to register a series of dynamically configured "Plugins" which are expressed as custom implementations of IRegistration.

Only then do I resolve my application start point.

One of the things that I would like a plugin to do is overwrite a service implementation. Something like this:

```
public class SomePlugin {
  public void Register(IKernel kernel) {
    kernel.RemoveComponent(typeof(DefaultServiceImplementation).FullName);
    kernel.Register(
            Component.For<IService>()
              .ImplementedBy<AlternateServiceImplementation>())
  }
}
```

However this does not work if any of the components already registered have a dependency on IService.

I know that I can register the plugins first, but that's limiting for several other reasons.  How can I fulfill my specific requirement?

Best thing I could come up with is something like

```
kernel.ResolvingComponent += (model, a, b) => {
  if(model.Service == typeof(IService))
    model.Implementation = typeof(AlternateServiceImplementation);
}
```

I think this could work in some limited scenarios but it is far from ideal.

Comment: so basically you want the *last* registered component to be the default component?

Comment: Sure that would be one implementation.  More specifically I'm interested in saying "Hey for component X which was previously implemented by X1 start using X2 as the default"

Comment: I mean is it *always* the last one registered? Or just sometimes? Would you mind using attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

George,

I believe what you're looking for is [IHandlerSelector](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/05/windsor-ihandlerselector.aspx).